# AngularJS weird error when creating simple directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create simple directive in angularJs and don't understand why the code below gives me following error:

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$compile/tplrt?p0=taWithMessage&p1=customButton.html
```

the code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var app = angular.module('aaa', []);

    app.directive("taWithMessage",function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: "customButton.html",
            replace: true
            };
        }

    );    

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-app="aaa">

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="customButton.html">

        <p>blah <em>blah<em>blah</em></em> blahHello, 
        <h2>kkk</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a name here" ng-keypress="valid=true"/></p>

    </script> 

        <form>

        <div ta-with-message></div>

            <input type="submit">

        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I don't understand is that it works when I replace `h2` with say `span` e.g.:

```
<p>blah <em>blah<em>blah</em></em> blahHello, 
<span>kkk</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a name here" ng-keypress="valid=true"/></p>
```

Does it have something to do with `display` of the element? Why would that be happening and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page of AngularJS error reference should help you:

- [Error: $compile:tplrt: Invalid Template Root](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile/tplrt)

### Further explanation

#### Auto-closing `<p>` tag

First (non-working) example in question contains a slight HTML markup error.

Why? Because `<p>` only allows *phrasing content* inside it. Heading tags are not phrasing content.  When browser sees a non-phrasing-content (for example, heading) tag inside `<p>`, it implicitly adds `</p>`.

Not putting `</p>` before `<h2>` is not an error, it's allowed by HTML specs:

> The end tag may be omitted if the `<p>` element is immediately followed by an `<address>`, `<article>`, … `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, … or another `<p>` element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an `<a>` element.

But in the end the first example in question is interpreted by browser like this:

```
    <p>blah <em>blah<em>blah</em></em> blahHello,</p> 
    <h2>kkk</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a name here" ng-keypress="valid=true"/>
```

Note how `</p>` changed its position from after `<input>` to before `<h2>`.

#### Incompatible directive template

This makes such directive template incompatible, because it then has *more than one root element*.
By AngularJS docs linked above, your directive template must have all its content inside a single top-level tag. However, your first example after browser interpretation turns out to have three top-level tags.

When you change `<h2>` to `<span>` your example is OK, since `<p>` doesn't auto-close anymore (`<span>` is phrasing content).

#### What you can do

Wrap your template in a `<div>`. Unlike `<p>`, it can contain any type of content. :)